# Props or State for Option Select

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand how I should identify a selected option on page load with the use of props or state. I understand that React uses a `value` or `defaultValue` on the `<select>` tag to establish the `selected` value for a controlled state and I understand that uncontrolled states are more flexible, but not recommended. In my current code I am attempting a controlled state value setup, but I have two issues that make my setup incorrect.

1) I have a prop with the value that should define the originally selected value on page load, but I know I can't set it as the state value so it doesn't fit the controlled environment setup.

2) When I set the prop as the `value`, I see the value selected on page load, but I am unable to select a different option from the dropdown. It doesn't change, which makes me believe that I need to use the state if I am using a controlled environment.

Based on the info above, what is the best solution? I'm also curious how this might be resolved if I switched to an uncontrolled setup. Would that be better based on my info? Any help would be appreciated.

Code (Note I am not using the state due to usage of prop in this scenario, but previously used and displayed for purpose of visualizing two approaches attempted):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class CategoryFilter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.value)
    }

  render() {
    console.log("CategoryFilter");
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(this.state.value);
    return (
        <div className="col-md-2 annotation-filter-section">
            <p>Category:</p>
            <select name="category" className="form-control annotation-filter-category" value={this.props.categoryQuery} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value=""></option>
                {
                    this.props.category.map(
                        (category) => { 
                                return ( <option key={category.categoryIdHash} value={category.categoryIdHash}>{category.categoryName}</option> ) 
                            }
                        )
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Code One level Up:

```
export default class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <CatgoryFilter category={this.props.category} categoryQuery={this.props.categoryQuery} />
        )
    }
}
```

Parent component:

```
export default class FeedContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
    }

    fetchList() {
        ...
        fetch(`${API_ROOT}` + '/api' + window.location.search, { compress: false })
                .then(res => {
                    return res.json();
                })  
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.setState({ 
                        category: data.category,
                        categoryQuery: data.categoryQuery,
                    });
                })

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <SearchForm category={this.state.category} categoryQuery={this.state.categoryQuery} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you decide to use props, the onChange event handler should have a way of changing the selected value in the parent component. Can you add the code of the component that passes categories to this component?

Comment: Why you are not able to set the state value with the props on componendidmount life cycle method

Comment: @JjagweDennis I will edit my question and add

Comment: @Harikrishnan that is a good point. For some reason I thought it was an anti-pattern to do so, but just read it is suggested in the documentation to do just that. I tried updating the code to `componentDidMount() { this.setState({value: this.props.categoryQuery })}`, but it doesn't look like it is being recognized in my state. When I console.log it says `undefined`. Maybe something is wrong with my constructor?

Comment: @cphil Can you put your full working code in codesandbox so let me check it

Comment: Are you getting the props.categoryQuery from a async action

Comment: @Harikrishnan does the edited question with parent and intermediate child component code provide you with that?

Comment: @cphil i have provided an answer please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are getting the `categoryQuery` from a fetch request you may not get the value on component mount time so you need to use componentWillReceiveProps life cycle method as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
export default class CategoryFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  componenetDidMount() {
   this.setState({value:this.props.categoryQuery})
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!isEqual(this.props, nextProps)) {
      this.setState({ value: nextProps.categoryQuery })
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.value)
  }

  render() {
    console.log("CategoryFilter");
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(this.state.value);
    return (
      <div className="col-md-2 annotation-filter-section">
        <p>Category:</p>
        <select name="category" className="form-control annotation-filter-category" value={this.props.categoryQuery} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value=""></option>
          {
            this.props.category.map(
              (category) => {
                return (<option key={category.categoryIdHash} value={category.categoryIdHash}>{category.categoryName}</option>)
              }
            )
          }
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can use `isEqual` from [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) for comparing the props.You need to compare the nextProps and this.props as componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method get triggered when any change in props occurs which results in state change and it will result in infinite re rendering.It is better to use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) as componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated.

Comment: This worked perfectly, but I guess one issue outside of the scope of this question is that I have multiple selects for a form submission so it appears on test that if I have more than one instance this solution does not work. i.e. If you have another component, but replace `category` with `team`, then it appears that the latter component will have a state, but the previous one will not.

Comment: Sorry. The issue is that I have multiple selects and am trying to roll out your solution to each select field, but it appears that when a page loads it only works for one select field, not all that have your solution applied. Does that make sense?

Comment: It looks like my issue is fixed if I modify your code in the constructor from `this.state = { value: '' };` to `value: props.categoryQuery`. Then it works across all select statements. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass an initial value, and then let the component handle its own state, here's one way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      value: props.initialValue,
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={value} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

render(<App initialValue="Hello"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bhft9m).

If you have to, you can lift the state up and pass down the handler:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const Child = ({ value, handleChange }) => (
  <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
)

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: props.initialValue,
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <Child handleChange={this.handleChange} value={value} />
    );
  }
}

render(<App initialValue="Hello" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yqgqfd?file=index.js).